# The scroll viewer lags for a second when there is lot of data in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I have a Grid and there are 7 columns and 6 rows. And there is listbox added for each row and column combination. Each list box is having arround 5 items (as default is 5, not increase above that). Each listbox item is having complex template. If i bind whole data then it takes 4 to 5 second to load. So to make fast loading, i am binding only that listbox which is visible on screen. so now it loads fast within a second. But when i scroll down, then the another data loads. But the scroll viewer lags for a second. So how can i scroll smothely ?
Any idea ?